# Can't publish my files to remote repository

Tags: git, github, git-lfs

```
Uploading LFS objects: 100% (1201/1201), 2.6 GB | 9.1 MB/s, done.
Enumerating objects: 20004, done.
Counting objects: 100% (20004/20004), done.
Delta compression using up to 12 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (11626/11626), done.
remote: fatal: pack exceeds maximum allowed size        /s   
error: RPC failed; curl 55 Send failure: Connection was aborted
send-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
Writing objects: 100% (20004/20004), 4.78 GiB | 23.39 MiB/s, done.
Total 20004 (delta 11193), reused 17185 (delta 8374), pack-reused 0
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date
```

I can't seem to publish my files to the remote repository. I have LFS enabled. How can I fix this??
[image]

Comment: Contact GitHub support. You have an overly large pack file, but since you're paying them for LFS support, they should be willing to help out here. Probably you need to use some of the fancy LFS "rewrite my repository for me to use LFS" options; I don't know what these are as my experience with LFS was "let's try this out ... no, we don't like it, let's not use it" a few years ago. :-)

Comment: @torek Thanks for the friendly reply. May I ask if there are any other alternatives to using LFS?

Comment: Our particular use case allowed us to just store the large files outside Git. This had a few slight drawbacks for us, which is why we looked into Git-LFS, but not enough to make us go for LFS.

Comment: @torek Aha ok thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so having found out that the error message was due to trying to push files that exceeded 2GB, I solved it by manually adding files incrementally.

---

How I did it:

On Git Bash

1. `git init`
2. `git remote add origin (link)`
3. `git lfs install`
4. `git pull origin master`
5. The proceeding to create, add, commit, and push `.gitattributes`
6. Track the LFS files: https://git-lfs.github.com/

Then go to Github Desktop
(For some reason, adding, committing, and pushing LFS doesn't work in Git Bash. But simply initializing LFS in Github Desktop, without having done `git lfs install` in Git Bash, also doesn't work either.)

Has to be in this particular order for some reason.

1. Add the repository and **make sure to Initialize Git LFS**
2. Manually move files into the Local Repository folder and make sure it does not exceed 2GB.
3. Add, commit, and push files

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're seeing here has nothing to do with Git LFS.  The problem is that the Git pack you're pushing to the remote is larger than 2 GB, which is the maximum limit that GitHub has to avoid denial-of-service problems and situations where people exceed maximum repository size limits.

You'd need to push your commits incrementally so that you end up with several smaller pushes.  For example, if your branch is `main`, you could push 1000 commits at a time with this approach.

```
$ git rev-list --reverse main | \
  perl -ne 'print unless $i++ % 1000;' | \
  xargs -I{} git push origin {}:main
```

If you don't care for Perl. Ruby can do something similar.

You should then follow it up with the regular push you intended to do in the first place.

Comment: Sorry, I am quite inexperienced with git. I tried to punch in the same code in Git bash but it still gives me an error. Perhaps I'm doing something wrong? Is there another way to push commits incrementally? I don't really know which files require LFS, so I have no idea which files to add and commit.

Comment: I've made a small change to the command.  If you're still seeing a problem, you'd need to include the message you're seeing when you run it, since we have no way of knowing what error you're seeing.  Also note that if your branch isn't `main`, you'll need to replace that with the branch name.